# What is the Evaluation Model of Bacon.js?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, bacon.js

Most resources on reactive programming, e.g. "A Survey on Reactive Programming" (Bainomugisha et al., 2012), introduce several characteristics by which different reactive solutions can be classified. One of these is which evaluation model is employed, that is, whether the reactive language (or library) is push-based or pull-based (or both).

Example: Let's take a look a this piece of pseudocode: `var c = a + b;` In a reactive environment, `c` is expected to *always* contain the sum of `a` and `b`. Accordingly, if `a` or `b` change, the value of `c` has to be recomputed. In a push-based solution, `a` and `b` notify `c` when their values have changed, so that `c`'s value can be recomputed instantly. In a pull-based solution, `c` looks up the current values of `a` and `b` as soon as the value `c` itself is being demanded. Thus, all recomputations are being delayed until `c`'s value is requested.

For quite some time now, I have tried to figure out what evaluation model is being employed by the JavaScript library Bacon.js. Let's assume the following:

```
var a = Bacon.constant(21); // Creates a Property
var b = Bacon.constant(21);
var c = a.combine(b, function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
});
```

According to [this section of the Bacon.js documentation](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#lazy-evaluation), combinators such as `combine` use lazy evaluation, that is, they "avoid evaluating values that aren't actually needed".

- Question 1: When are values "actually" needed?
- Question 2: Is it safe to assume that--at least in the case of the example above--Bacon.js employs a pull-based approach? Or am I mixing things up here?

However, towards the end of the section, the Bacon.js documentation mentions that if one wants "[t]o force evaluation at the time of original event, [one] can just use `flatMap`". Really, now I am confused:

- Question 3: Respectively, is it safe to assume that Bacon.js employs a push-based evaluation model whenever I use `flatMap`? Or am I mixing things up here--again?
- Question 4: I cannot really reproduce the example from above using `flatMap` instead of `combine`. Does that mean that depending on what I am trying to do, Bacon.js sometimes employs a pull-based propagation of change, and sometimes it comes up with a push-based one?

To the one who can provide clarification, I would be very greatful. :P

Comment: i don't know anything about bacon.js in particular, but when i implimented both a push and pull pattern in vanilla, your code seems to match up with the pull approach: http://jsfiddle.net/nf331L5n/

Comment: I think you're rather looking for the section https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#atomic-updates

Comment: @Bergi Actually, that has not much to do with my question. However, it is also very interesting! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

1. Value is "needed" when a Subscriber calls the `value()` method of an event. This happens in all `.on Value` subscribers for instance. Combinators like `map` and `combine` do not evaluate the input values until their respective value is required. On the other hand, `flatMap(f)` needs to evaluate, because it uses the value to spawn a new stream using the provided function `f`. Also `scan` is currently eager.
2. As described above, it's a mixture of push and pull in the sense that evaluation occurs when necessary. In fact, Bacon.js is not based on any research papers and does not comply with any theoretical models.
3. No, don't assume any models. Instead, use referentially transparent functions and let the system decide when it needs to evaluate them.
4. Surely you cannot reproduce the same functionality with `flatMap` that you can with `combine`.

Comment: I assume OP means to reproduce `c = combine(a, b, +)` with `c = a.flatMap (a) -> b.map (b) -> a+b`

Comment: Exactly. Actually, since I was not able to reproduce my example with eager operators, I figured depending on what I am trying to do, Bacon.js gives me either eager or lazy evaluation. Is that true? Or is there an eager way for everything as well as a lazy way for everything?